# Unable to perform a not-in

Tags: c#, linq

I have a two objects, one `AnotherList` that contains an array of ints and the other `MyFolder` that contains an array of objects `FolderItem` that contains an array of objects `ItemKeyword` that have two strings (in a key-value-pair style).

I want to return a `List<FolderItem>` from MyFolder that **are not** referenced in the AnotherList. I can get a list of items that **are** in the list and have included the Linq for that at the bottom.

I have been fighting with .`Contains` and `.Except` extensions all day but keep getting errors. I'm hoping that this is easy for someone.

This is a case where code speaks a thousand words so here it is.

The Linq query at the end returns only one `FolderItem` at the moment `folderItemID=25`.

I need it to return all the `FolderItems` `folderItemID=26,27,28` instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

namespace temp
{
    class MyFolder
    {
        public FolderItem[] items { get; set; }
    }

    class FolderItem
    {
        public int folderItemID { get; set; }
        public ItemKeyword[] keywords { get; set; }
    }

    class ItemKeyword
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    class AnotherList
    {
        public AnotherListItem[] items { get; set; }
    }

    class AnotherListItem
    {
        public int dataID { get; set; }
    }




    public class TestingClass
    {

        public static void mainApp()
        {
            AnotherList List1 = new AnotherList()
                {
                    items = new AnotherListItem[]{
                        new AnotherListItem(){dataID=1},
                        new AnotherListItem(){dataID=2},
                        new AnotherListItem(){dataID=3}
                    }};

            MyFolder List2 = new MyFolder()
            {
                items = new FolderItem[]
                {
                    new FolderItem()
                        {
                            folderItemID=25, keywords= new ItemKeyword[]
                                {
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="dataID", value="1"},
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="description", value="some text"},
                                }
                    },
                    new FolderItem()
                        {
                            folderItemID=26, keywords= new ItemKeyword[]
                                {
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="dataID", value="4"},
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="description", value="some other text"},
                                }
                        },
                    new FolderItem()
                        {
                            folderItemID=27, keywords= new ItemKeyword[]
                                {
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="dataID", value="9"},
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="description", value="even more other text"},
                                }
                        },
                    new FolderItem()
                        {
                            folderItemID=28, keywords= new ItemKeyword[]
                                {
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="dataID", value="12"},
                                    new ItemKeyword(){key="description", value="3"},
                                }
                        }
                }};

            List<FolderItem> res = (from someItems in List2.items
                                    from itemKeywords in someItems.keywords
                                    join otherItems in List1.items on itemKeywords.value equals otherItems.dataID.ToString()
                                    where itemKeywords.key == "dataID"
                                    select someItems).ToList<FolderItem>();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"but I keep getting errors"*.  You should really share with us, **what** errors you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `Any` extension method. You can confidently copy and paste the code below since it is meant to work with the code you provided...

```
        List<FolderItem> res = List2.items.Where(x => !List1.items.Any(y => x.keywords.FirstOrDefault(z => z.key == "dataID").value == y.dataID.ToString())).ToList();
```

Comment: All answers really answered my question but this was simplest. A further question though...how could I handle the fact that the Key "dataID" is missing from FolderItem?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on how you want your application to handle this situation. What's supposed to happen if a `FolderItem` doesn't have that key?

Comment: Sorry yes...I would not want it to appear in your resulting List<FolderItem>

Answer (score 2):

First grab all of the IDs that we don't want and stick them into a set for fast searching:

```
var badIDs = new HashSet<int>(List1.items.Select(item => item.dataID));
```

Then get all of the folders where they are not contained in that set:

```
var goodFolders = List2.items.Where(folder => 
    !badIDs.Contains(folder.folderItemID));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = List2.items.Where(fi => !List1.items.Any(al => 
    al.dataID.ToString() == fi.keywords.Single(k => k.key == "dataID").value));
```

Assuming a `FolderItem` only has one `ItemKeyword` with `key="dataID"`.